Find all $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x^2)+2yf(x)+(f(y))^2$ is a perfect square for all $x, y \in \mathbb{N}$
Question: Find all $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x^2)+2yf(x)+(f(y))^2$ is a perfect square for all $x, y \in \mathbb{N}$.
I believe that the only such function is $\boxed{f(n)=n}$, but I don't know how to prove this.
I started by setting $x=y=1$, which forces $3f(1)+(f(1))^2$ to be a perfect square. Using the difference of squares factorisation yields $f(1)=1$.
I also made the basic observation that $f$ cannot be a constant function.
At this point, I made the following two observations:

Set $x=1$. Then, $(f(y))^2+2y+1$ is a perfect square, say $k^2$, for all $y \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, $$2y+1=k^2-(f(y))^2=(k-f(y))(k+f(y))$$ If we let $d$ be a divisor of $2y+1$ with $d<\sqrt{2y+1}$, then we can say that $$\begin{cases} k-f(y)=d \\ k+f(y)=\frac{2y+1}{d} \end{cases} \implies \boxed{f(y)=\frac{2y+1}{2d}-\frac{d}{2}}$$ From this, it can be deduced that $\boxed{f \left(\frac{p-1}{2} \right)=\frac{p-1}{2}}$ for all primes $p$.

I also established bounds on $f(y)$ since $$\frac{2y+1}{2\sqrt{2y+1}}-\frac{\sqrt{2y+1}}{2} \leq f(y) \leq \frac{2y+1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \implies \boxed{0 \leq f(y) \leq y}$$

Again, set $x=1$. Then, $(f(y))^2+2y+1$ is a perfect square.


Note that $(f(y))^2$ is either $0$ or $1$ mod $4$.
$2y$ is $2$ mod $4$ if $y$ is odd and $0$ mod $4$ if $y$ is even.

Since all odd perfect squares are $1$ mod $4$ and all even perfect squares are $0$ mod $4$, it follows that:

If $y$ is odd, then $(f(y))^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{4} \implies f(y)$ is odd.
If $y$ is even, then $(f(y))^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{4} \implies f(y)$ is even.

Therefore, $\boxed{f(y) \text{ has the same parity as } y}$.
However, I am unsure of how to proceed (mainly because I don't know how to work with the $f(x^2)$ term). I tried using some of the ideas from this Greek TST 2018 Question, but again, the $f(x^2)$ term is messing with me.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The title states "$2x f(y)$" and your first phrase states "$2 f(x) y$", which is it? (Shouldn't it be $2 f(x) f(y)$?) :-)

$0\notin\mathbb{N}$?

There are some solutions in this AOPS post, though I've not verified them.

@CalvinLin Yes to your other two questions, and thanks for finding that!

Credits to Calvin Lin for finding this link (AOPS thread with the question) which contains a few solutions to this question. I reproduce of the solutions below:
Let $P(n, m) : f(m^2) + 2f(m)n + f(n)^2$ be a perfect square.
$P(1, 1) \implies 3f(1) + f(1)^2 \text{ is a perfect square, but } (f(1) + 2)^2 > 3f(1) + f(1)^2 \geq (f(1) + 1)^2.$
Hence $f(1) = 1$.
Let $p > 2$ be a prime.
$P\left(\frac{p - 1}{2}, 1\right) \implies f\left(\frac{p - 1}{2}\right) = \frac{p - 1}{2}.$ (proof shown in the original post)
Now, fix an integer $n \geq 1$.
$P\left(\frac{p - 1}{2}, n\right) \implies 
f(n)^2 - n^2 = \left(a_p - n - \frac{p - 1}{2}\right)\left(a_p + n + \frac{p - 1}{2}\right)$
for all primes $p > 2$, where $a_p$ is some positive integer. Hence
$a_p + n + \frac{p - 1}{2} \mid f(n)^2 - n^2 \text{ and } a_p + n + \frac{p - 1}{2} > \frac{p - 1}{2}.$
Take large prime $p$ to get $f(n)^2 = n^2$.
Therefore, $P(n, m)$ becomes
$m^2 - f(m)^2 + (f(m) + f(n))^2 \text{ is a perfect square.}$
Fix $n > 0$.
$P\left(\frac{p - 1}{2}, n\right) \implies 
n^2 - f(n)^2 = \left(a_p - f(n) - \frac{p - 1}{2}\right)\left(a_p + f(n) + \frac{p - 1}{2}\right)$
for any prime $p > 2$, where $a_p$ is a positive integer. Take $p$ large enough to get $n^2 = f(n)^2$, so $f(n) = n$.
